# What's the difference between Metaplex's set_and_verify_collection and set_and_verify_sized_collection_item?

Tags: collections, solana, nft, verify, metaplex

The Metaplex documentation descriptions of both instructions are the same: https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/instruction/index.html

Answer (score 0):

They are doing basically the same there is only one small difference:

`set_and_verify_sized_collection` is used for sized collections, `set_and_verify_collection` is used for "normal"/unsized ones. You have to use different instructions because the sized collection one does additional checks and updates.

Sized collections have a amount of maximum NFTs in the collection stored in the collection NFTs metadata.